# Multiple Asp.net Core aplicattions runinng on the same container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, cloud

I have aws generic container enviroment. And for some reason I want to run multiple dotnet webapi applications on the same container. I know it is possible. Because it's already seen someone do it passing a bash script into the ENTRYPOINT. This script creates one kestrel-$API.service file for each application and put them on the /etc/systemd/system/ directory and it runs systemctl to enable those services.

But I want to know if there is a better or more elegant way to do it.
The reason I don't want to use multi container is because in the Dockerrun file I have to specify a memory limit for each container and because I would have to create a container network.

Comment: To take the most out of Docker, I'd still recommend using separate containers. In the case you still need multiple services in one container for some reason, have you checked the [official documentation example](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)? Entrypoint/Cmd script plus Supervisord seems an elegant and popular solution to manage the processes.

Comment: This is a bad idea all around. The whole entire point of containerization is having discrete applications that can be stopped, started, replaced. scaled, etc. without impact on the rest of the environment. Deploying multiple applications in a single container literally negates all the benefit of containers. More to the point, why even have multiple applications. If you only want to manage one container, then deploy a monolith there. Any benefit gained by distribution is lost, because things aren't distributed.